# How to mock keycloak class of keycloak.admin.client.Keycloak using mockito?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, keycloak

We integrate keycloak-admin-client dependency to add and manage user of keycloak from java application and we have added testcases using mockito so we need to mock keycloak builders for excluding original connection of keycloak. Below is one example, which we have tried but it throws MissingMethodInnovationExceprion.

```
KeycloakBuilder builder = Mockito.mock(KeycloakBuilder.class);
        keycloakAdminConfig.serverUrl = "/abc";
        keycloakAdminConfig.realmName = "java";
        keycloakAdminConfig.clientId = "hhhj";
        keycloakAdminConfig.clientSecret = "hhb";
        keycloakAdminConfig.userName = "h";
        keycloakAdminConfig.password = "hhh";
        Keycloak keycloak = Mockito.mock(Keycloak.class);
        Mockito.when(builder.build()).thenReturn(keycloak);
```

```
        UserRepresentation user = new UserRepresentation();
        user.setEnabled(true);
        user.setUsername(username);
        user.setFirstName(organizationDto.getFirstName());
        user.setLastName(organizationDto.getLastName());
        user.setEmail(organizationDto.getEmail());
        RealmResource realmResource = keycloak.realm(keycloakAdminConfig.realmName);
        UsersResource userRessource = realmResource.users();
        Response response = userRessource.create(user);
```

Comment: Can you add code about how KeycloakBuilder is created, which you want to test ?

Comment: @Pankaj Thank you for your reply. As you can see above the second code of block, we would mock create user functionality from keycloak.

Comment: I'm not sure how KeycloakBuilder is passed/created in method but if you inject KeycloakBuilder via constructor or setter method then you can mock. Constructor Injection example - https://freecontent.manning.com/understanding-constructor-injection/